# Place divs in alphabetical order by data attribute

Tags: jquery

I am trying to place my divs into alphabetical order and failing with my jQuery code:

```
var $wrapper = $('.modal .row');
$wrapper.find('.txt_center').sort(function (a, b) {
return +a.getAttribute('data-ename') > +b.getAttribute('data-ename'); }).appendTo($wrapper);
```

The html code is below:

```
<div class="modal" id="staff" style="text-align: center;">

<div class="row txt_center">
    <div class="txt_center" data-ename="William Black">
        <p class="profile-name"><strong>William Black</strong>

        </p>
        <p class="profile-details">Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="txt_center" data-ename="Ariel White">
        <p class="profile-name"><strong>Ariel White</strong>

        </p>
        <p class="profile-details">Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="txt_center" data-ename="John Smith">
        <p class="profile-name"><strong>John Smith</strong>

        </p>
        <p class="profile-details">Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="txt_center" data-ename="Vanessa Mae">
        <p class="profile-name"><strong>Vanessa Mae</strong>

        </p>
        <p class="profile-details">Title</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me with my problem on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8rhg4337/1/

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: if you replace the inner div with `ul` and `li` then you can sort it. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8rhg4337/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below. It's close to your function. It gets the data attribute 'ename' and returns it.
`$(a).data('ename')` instead of `+a.getAttribute('data-ename')`

```js
var $wrapper = $('.modal .row');

$wrapper.find('.txt_center').sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).data('ename') > $(b).data('ename');
}).appendTo($wrapper);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal" id="staff" style="text-align: center;">

<div class="row txt_center">
    <div class="txt_center" data-ename="William Black">
        <p class="profile-name"><strong>William Black</strong>

        </p>
        <p class="profile-details">Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="txt_center" data-ename="Ariel White">
        <p class="profile-name"><strong>Ariel White</strong>

        </p>
        <p class="profile-details">Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="txt_center" data-ename="John Smith">
        <p class="profile-name"><strong>John Smith</strong>

        </p>
        <p class="profile-details">Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="txt_center" data-ename="Vanessa Mae">
        <p class="profile-name"><strong>Vanessa Mae</strong>

        </p>
        <p class="profile-details">Title</p>
    </div>
</div>
```